# Surface pro 7 (USB-C) to UWQHD (DP, HDMI, DVI)?

Tags: resolution, microsoft-surface, widescreen

Is it possible to use a UWQHD 3440x1440 monitor for my surface pro7?

The surface only have USB-C and the monitor have HDMI (HDCP 1.4), DP and DVI. Do I need a specific adapter or do all adapters work (e.g. DP->USB-C)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to use a UWQHD 3440x1440 monitor for my Surface Pro 7

Yes

> Do I need a specific adapter or do all adapters work (e.g. DP->USB-C)?

Microsoft indicates the following is required to do what you want.

> - A Surface USB-C to display adapter.  This can be any of the following:
>
>   - [Surface USB-C to DisplayPort adapter](https://www.microsoft.com/p/surface-usb-c-to-displayport-adapter/8sxhsbstrnwn)
>   - [Surface USB-C to HDMI adapter](https://www.microsoft.com/p/surface-usb-c-to-hdmi-adapter/94chb2m80s54)
>   - [Surface USB-C to VGA adapter](https://www.microsoft.com/p/surface-usb-c-to-vga-adapter/91sx3zzh91tf)
> - A Surface device that has USB-C port.
> - An external display and video cable.

Worth pointing out that I was able to find numerous USB Type C to DisplayPort/HDMI/VGA cables when I looked for one.  T**here is nothing special about the Surface branded adapters.**

Source: [Set up a Surface USB-C to display adapter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4344942/set-up-a-surface-usb-c-to-display-adapter)

Comment: Questions seeking specific hardware recommendations are out of scope here at Super User.  Since this question was asking, "is it possible" it's currently within scope, which is the reason I specifically point out there is nothing special about the branded display adapters.  *If you are looking for a product recommendation I won't be making one.* I only included the links to the products, the article linked to, due to the fact I was quoting the article itself.  I notice several reviews for those products, one indicate it didn't work, but their Surface didn't have a Type-C port. Read the article

Comment: Thank you very much! So I assume that I can use any brand for the adapter without losing the resolution :-)